# How to enable blinking text in ConEmu?

Tags: conemu

Gurus

I am trying to make text blink by ANSI sequence "ESC[31;1;5mRafaESC[0m" 
It works in mintty but does not work in ConEmu (the latest version 140310).

How to enable blinking test in ConEmu?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Blinking text is not supported in Windows console. So ConEmu does not support it too.

On the other hand, ANSI defines **only 8 console colors**, but Windows defines **16 colors**. And only using bold/blink/underline codes you can force your console to use upper 8 colors from 16 color table.